# How to define a list of whichever specific type inherits from a class?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, abstract-class

I would like to create an abstract class, of which any deriving type should implement a property called `Entries`, which is a List of all the instances of that type. My goal is that in the abstract class, I want to be able to manage a list of instances and perform some operations on them that would be exactly the same for all inheriting types, but I also would like the resulting list to be defined as containing instances of the specific subtypes for easier access without casting.

Given the abstract class called `Person`, and a class called `Employee` that inherits from it, as an example:

- `Person` should be able to access and modify `Entries` as if it were a `List<Person>`.
- `Employee` should be able to access, modify and expose that same `Entries` as if it were a `List<Employee>`, thus giving the outside world access to all members that are specifically defined in itself.
- The previous point should then also be true for any other subclasses of `Person`, which would then see `Entries` as a list of themselves.

Is it possible to achieve this in C# without needing to cast `Person` into `Employee` everytime you access the list, and without needing to define a separate list on each subtype that would need to be kept synchronized with the List that's accessible by the abstract class?

Comment: Something like `abstract class Employee<T> where T : Employee`? And then you can have `List<T> Entries`, so the type would always be what you define in the derived class

Comment: @devNull It's the other way around. `Person` is the abstract class, not `Employee`.

Comment: @devNull I tried that, but it doesn't seem to work because when you turn the abstract class into a generic, you then also have to pass a type into the constraint. (As a sidenote, I'm not very experienced when it comes to what can be done with generics so I hope I'm using the correct terminology for everything.)

Comment: @Andii yeah that's my bad, I missed passing the type to the constraint. And it should be `Person`. So `abstract class Person<T> where T : Person<T>` is the correct syntax. And then your derived class would be `class Employee : Person<Employee>`

Comment: This approach leads to inheretance madness where types that look like they extend something actually extend some other common root. I dont believe it is possible to use the containing type as a generic parameter, so that is not possible. You might want to consider using an IEnumerable interface instead, implemeted abstractly and then every inhereting class would implement an IEnumerable of its own type ( as IEnumerable is covariant ).

Comment: Also, in an upcoming version of C#, overriden methods may choose to return a more derived type than the originally defined, which should solve this problem like `abstract IEnumerable<Person>` -> `override IEnumerable<Employee>`

Comment: The generic approach does seem to work, although I agree that it gets a little messy, especially when more inheritance gets added in between. I might end up still using it, it's something to think about. It's good to know this will be addressed in C#'s future, and I'm also interested in the IEnumerable idea, which I will probably have to read up on to understand. Thanks for the ideas so far!

Comment: One note on the pattern I suggested above: you may not want to expose it externally as it can be easily misused (e.g. `class Employee : Person<Manager>`). There's an open proposal to add a similar, but safer, feature to the language: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/169

Comment: The above proposal basically looks like exactly what I was looking for, and what I was hoping might already exist in some way I wasn't aware of.